# How to edit custom table data in frontend

Tags: database, mysql, forms, front-end, table

I am trying to edit the data from the table in the frontend. when I click the edit the form doesn't anything it show only empty field

**Html Code**

```
<form action="" id="postjob" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="team_uniqueid">UniqueID:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team_uniqueid" id="team_uniqueid" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="team_firstname">FirstName:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team_firstname" id="team_firstname" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="team_lastname">LastName:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team_lastname" id="team_lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="team_emailid">EmailId:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="team_emailid" id="team_emailid" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      
        <div class="full_wrap">
                <div class="sub_wrap">
                    <select name="page_id" id="page_id">
                    <?php
                    global $post;
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
                    $posts = get_posts($args);
                    foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                    <select>
                        <option class="au">Australia</option>
                        <option class="Ind">India</option>
                        <option class="US">United States</option>
                        <option class="UK">United Kingdom</option>
                    
                    </select>

                </div>
        </div>                              
        
        </tr>
        
     
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" name="insert_member">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Edit Code**

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $record = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE team_emailid = '".$id."'");
    

    if($record->num_rows){
        $n = $record->fetch_array();
        $team_uniqueid = $n['team_uniqueid'];
        $team_firstname = $n['team_firstname'];
        $team_lastname = $n['team_lastname'];
        $team_emailid1 = $n['team_emailid'];

    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `SELECT *` you're running a query to get ALL so by default it returns an array of results, even if it only finds one.  So you may need to specify which offset in the array you're looking for.

Comment: @TonyDjukic as you mentioned it return as array so I have changes this line

**$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT team_uniqueid,team_firstname,team_lastname,team_emailid FROM $tablename WHERE team_emailid = '".$id."'");**

It start working

Comment: @TonyDjukic it is working now

Comment: Great news.  You should post your findings as an answer and accept it so that the next person who encounters this can use your answer to solve their problem. :-)  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!
To edit the existing field, you need to put the values inside your input fields. You can do that in this way-

```
<tr>
     <td><label for="team_uniqueid">UniqueID:</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="team_uniqueid" id="team_uniqueid" value="<?php echo $team_uniqueid; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

I hope, this will help.